# YouTube Data API (v3) search filters are broken

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

*Note: I am using a YouTube Iframe from a webview inside a Chrome App.*

This is what [YouTube's API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) states:

`videoSyndicated`

> The videoSyndicated parameter lets you to restrict a search to only
>   videos that can be played outside youtube.com. If you specify a value
>   for this parameter, you must also set the type parameter's value to
>   video.

`videoLicense`

> The videoLicense parameter filters search results to only include
>   videos with a particular license. YouTube lets video uploaders choose
>   to attach either the Creative Commons license or the standard YouTube
>   license to each of their videos. If you specify a value for this
>   parameter, you must also set the type parameter's value to video.

`videoEmbeddable`

> The videoEmbeddable parameter lets you to restrict a search to only
>   videos that can be embedded into a webpage. If you specify a value for
>   this parameter, you must also set the type parameter's value to video.

Even if I turn them all on, I still get error messages like

`This video contains content from X`

[image]

Example video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMSIR210mRg

**Q: Why is this the case, and how do I ensure that the search results only include the videos that are playable from my website?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate check for copyright claims. The legal copyright holder of some content on the video ( usually the music ) has the legal right to restrict or block the embed on certain sites. This info is currently not available through the YouTube API.

Answer (score 1):

I realized it's not that the filters are broken, it's that the videos have domain-specific blacklists. For example, certain videos cannot be played from mobile devices or in my case, from a chrome app that has `chrome-extension://` domain.